# JavaScript access iframe inner variables in Firefox

Tags: javascript, variables, firefox, dom, iframe

The following works well in Internet Explorer and Chrome, but NOT in Firefox.
The idea is to change the background of the parent body after every click within the iframe.
Note that Firefox somehow knows to set the blue background initially.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head><script>
  function polling() {
    if (window.iframeId.change) document.body.style.background = 'red';
    if (!window.iframeId.change) document.body.style.background = 'blue';
    setTimeout(polling, 1000); }
</script></head>
  <body onload="polling();">
    <iframe id="iframeId" src="frame.html" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**frame.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head><script>var change=false;</script></head>
  <body style="background:yellow;" onclick="change=!change;"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could make it work:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function polling() {
            if (window.frames['theIframe'].change) {
                document.body.style.background = 'red';
            }
            else {
                document.body.style.background = 'blue';
            }

            setTimeout(polling, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="polling();">
    <iframe id="iframeId" src="frame.html" name="theIframe" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**frame.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var change = false;
        function load() {
            document.onclick = doClick;
        }        
        function doClick() {
            change = !change;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body style="background: yellow;"  onload="load()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Funny though that now in Firefox (only) also the right-click works :)